# Why don't my date picker and time picker show up?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

My date picker and time picker don't show up next to the "Enter date:" and "Enter time:" fields:  http://heightsdental.com/RequestAppt.php. There are php include statements in the code, and when they're not there: http://evamagnus.com/RequestAppt.php, the date and time pickers are displayed.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ptTimeSelect.js"></script>

<script src="js/dimensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js">
     </script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js">
    </script>

<?php
include "Banner.html";
include "header.html"
?>

<div id="form">
<div id="contain">

    <form action="http://www1.budgethostingweb.com/cgi-bin/hosting/user_formmail.cgi" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="account" value="dentist">
    <input type="hidden" name="cata" value="accounts">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="index.php" />

      <table class="form_demo">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="name">
              Name
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="input_full" type="text" id="name" name="name" required="required" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td><label for="email">
              Email
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="input_full" type="email" id="email" name="email" required="required" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="cc">
              <abbr title="Courtesy Copy">CC</abbr>
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cc" name="cc" value="1" />
            <label for="cc">
              Send me a copy of this email
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="tel">
              Phone
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input class="input_full" type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" required="required" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="priority_normal">
              Priority
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="priority" id="priority_urgent" value="Urgent">
            <label for="priority_urgent">
              Urgent
            </label>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <input type="radio" name="priority" id="priority_normal" value="Normal" checked="checked">
            <label for="priority_normal">
              Normal
            </label>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="date">Enter a date:</label>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <input class="input_xlarge" type="text" id="date" name="date" required="required" />    

    <script>
      (function($){
         var pickerOpts = {
            minDate: new Date(),
            maxDate: "+3m,",
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showOn: "button",

            buttonImage: "images/cal.png",
            };
    $("#date").datepicker(pickerOpts);
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Enter a time: </td>
    <td><input id="time1" name="s2Time1" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#time1').ptTimeSelect({ popupImage: 'Select Time' });
    </script>
    </td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="description">
              Reason for<br />
              appointment
            </label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <textarea id="description" name="description" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="2">To prevent automated spam posts, <br>please type in the access code
displayed: <p><img alt="Access code"
src="http://www1.budgethostingweb.com/cgi-bin/captcha/imagegen.cgi?x-factor=1"/></p></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Access Code:</td> <td><input class="medium" name="access" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <hr />
      <p class="clearfix">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="float_left" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="float_right">
      </p>

    </form>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code, not just links to the result!

Comment: Please include your relevant source code. Try to avoid forcing others to have to visit external links when possible.

Comment: @KenLi they work on the evamagnus link but not on the heightsdental link (also using latest chrome on windows 7)

Comment: actually, it works on the second link, not the first

Comment: It's a lot better to show code examples than just providing external links, as these can be hard to debug, or even just porn... :)

Comment: Although I agree with "show your code" in this special case it really was easier and faster to find the error on the actual site since it had nothing to do with the code itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File missing at below path:

http://heightsdental.com/js/jquery.ui.core.js

http://heightsdental.com/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js

Comment: Thanks.  The files are there now, and the datepicker is there now, but it doesn't look right, so I'll figure it out.  The timepicker still does not display.

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery UI script include is failing.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look into chrome's dev tools reveals:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://heightsdental.com/js/jquery.ui.core.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://heightsdental.com/js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' RequestAppt.php:159
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function RequestAppt.php:167
```

Meaning: Your JavaScript includes point to files that do not exist.

Looking into [your js subdir](http://heightsdental.com/js/) shows: They really are not there.

(It's bad btw. to allow indexing, disable [directory listing](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/))

Comment: Thanks, MiDo.  I placed "Options -Indexes" in the htaccess file of evamagnus.com.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, also do it for heightsdental.com - this will disable the directory listing. But this is not why your datepickers do not show, for this you have to upload `jquery.ui.core.js` and `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` to the `/js/` directory

Comment: Yes, I uploaded those files.  I don't have access to the heightsdental server.  The dentist hosts the site with a third party.

Comment: I could contact their hosting service and ask them to do it, though.

Comment: I get "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function" RequestAppt.php:167, which I assume means, "line 167," but the only code on line 167 is </tr>, the closing tag for the "Reason for appointment" field.

Comment: This would be a new question, the date/timepickers not showing seems to be solved. Would be great if you accepted on of the 3 (all correct) answers for this question and would post a new one for your new problem.