# Object has no method datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'` in my javascript here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $("#birthday").datepicker({changeMonth: true});
});
</script>
```

Here's the birthday item that I'm trying to add it to:

```
<!--// BIRTHDAY //-->
<li class="field">
    <label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
    <div class="field"><input type="text" id="birthday" name="birthday" value="" class="" /></div>
</li>
```

As you can see, I'm including the source for jquery ui just above where I'm trying to use the datepicker. I got the URL from http://jqueryui.com/docs/Downloading_jQuery_UI so I'm pretty sure it's a valid URL. I also tried uploading the file and linking to the local copy and I still got the same error. What else can I try?

EDIT:

I do have the jquery library loaded using this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` and verified with this bit of script:

```
if (jQuery) {
    alert("jQuery library is loaded!");
}
```

Comment: Try looking in your browser's inspector (Chrome Dev Tools, Firebug, etc) - are there any 404 errors?

Comment: just as a test, try: $.noConflict() in your doc ready to see if its conflicting jqueries

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nyhCF/

Comment: Include <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>

Comment: noConflict gave the error $ is not a function. That means there isn't a conflict, right @PhillipSchmidt?

Comment: @jaimerump well, technically yes, but only because what it ***really*** means is that you haven't imported jQuery. You need to go find the googleapis link for jquery and add that to the page as well. Or of course you can do it locally

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I have it included in another file that I'm bringing in with a PHP require, and I also tried including it directly in the view file where I'm having the problem and I'm still getting the same error. I'm using 1.7.2 on the page. The datepicker should only require something like 1.3, correct?

Comment: @jaimerump yeah, probably. But there's no doubt about it -- `$ is not a function` == no jQuery getting loaded. Do me a favor and try and load the page in IE (really it doesn't matter what browser), hit f12, go to script, and see if you're getting a 404 on the call to get jQuery.

Comment: @jaimerump also, are you by any chance loading this page via ajax?

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt I'm not seeing any 404s in any browser, and I don't have any Ajax calls on the page. I'm not having any problems with jQuery being included on any other pages, and I'm loading it with the php require on every other page.

Comment: @jaimerump hmm. one more thing, then. Try jQuery.noConflict() rather than $.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt same error again, `Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function`. With it commented out I just get the `datepicker is not a function` error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14747/discussion-between-phillip-schmidt-and-jaimerump)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From our discussion, we found that the $ variable (an alias to `jQuery`) was not behaving normally. Usually, this is because another JS plugin has changed `$` to represent something else. To get around this, you can wrap your jQuery code like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    //all jQuery code which uses $ needs to be inside here
});
```

This will change the meaning of $ within the scope of the function.

Answer (score 3):

You may be having a jQuery conflict. Give it a try in noConflict mode like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: It's better to link to your answer in another post under comments if the answer is exactly identical.

Answer (score 1):

$ will work like

```
$(function($) {
    $( "#dateTasted" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($){
         var pickerOpts = {
           // minDate: new Date(),
            //maxDate: "+3m,",
            showButtonPanel: true,
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/cal.png",
            };
    $("#birthday").datepicker(pickerOpts);
      })(jQuery);
</script>
```

[link source solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760582/why-dont-my-date-picker-and-time-picker-show-up)